# Display list of groups that certain user is member of Bash

Tags: linux, bash

The task is to display a list of groups from /etc/group that certain user is member of. User name is passed as a parameter. My current code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cat /etc/group | grep -w "$1" | cut -d ":" -f1
```

The problem is that there are certain lines that contain user name but they are not groups that user is member of. Example: syslog:x:106: and adm:x:4:syslog,username. The only thing I want as a result is adm but my current code will also output syslog. Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: The only wayt o get that output seems to be if the user name is `syslog` or `x` or `106`.

Comment: @Micha An English-language link might be more useful. Perhaps try [/q/11710552](/q/11710552)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `groups` command:

> ```
> $ groups --help
> Usage: groups [OPTION]... [USERNAME]...
> Print group memberships for each USERNAME or, ...
> ```

Comment: I'm not asking for a command integrated into terminal that would work, but for a solution with my code. However the "groups" does the same output as my code so I guess my implementation is right. Thanks!

Comment: If you're happy with the output of your code, it can be more simplified into: `awk -F":" -v pat="$1" '$0~pat {print $1}' /etc/group`